# Unit Testing a Service That Uses AngularFireAuth and Mocking authState

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firebase, jasmine, angularfire2

I have been going round in circles trying to unit test a Service (`AuthService`) that depends upon `AngularFireAuth`.

I am trying to find a way to mock, or highjack the Observable `AngularFireAuth.authState` instead of the Service actually talking to Firebase.

Here is my test spec:

```
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

const authState: firebase.User = null;
const mockAngularFireAuth: any = { authState: Observable.of(authState) };

describe('AuthService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseAppConfig)],
      providers: [
        { provider: AngularFireAuth, useValue: mockAngularFireAuth },
        AuthService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should be defined', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  }));

  it('.authState should be null', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service.authState).toBe(null);
  }));
});
```

And here is my (simplified) Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private authState: firebase.User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { this.init(); }

  private init(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((authState) => {
      if (authState === null) {
        this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
          .then((authState) => {
            this.authState = authState;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw new Error(error.message);
          });
      } else {
        this.authState = authState;
      }
    }, (error) => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
  }

  public get currentUser(): firebase.User {
    return this.authState ? this.authState : undefined;
  }

  public get currentUserObservable(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }

  public get currentUid(): string {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.uid : undefined;
  }

  public get isAnonymous(): boolean {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false;
  }

  public get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.authState;
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

I get the error `Property 'authState' is private and only accessible within class 'AuthService'.`

Of course it is, but I don't want to actually access it — I want to mock or highjack it so I can control it's value from within my test spec. I believe I am way off-course with my code here.

Please note I am using version `^4` of AngularFire2 and there were breaking changes introduced; documented here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encapsulated members can be reflected.

The hard way:

```
expect(Reflect.get(service, 'authState')).toBe(null);
```

The easy way:

```
expect(service['authState']).toBe(null);
expect((service as any).authState).toBe(null);
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I then set the `authState` too? Say if I wanted to test the `currentUid` getter in the Service. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome. Similarly, with `Reflect.set(...)`. Or even easier, `service['authState'] = ...` or `(service as any).authState = ...`. It looks like purely TS question, I would suggest to add `typescript` tag to the question instead of `firebase` since it's relevant here.

Comment: Fantastic! Just to educate myself; even though I'm no longer overriding `AngularFireAuth` with a mock (i.e. no longer doing `{ provider: AngularFireAuth, useValue: mockAngularFireAuth }`) how come there are no calls to Firebase? `init` in the Service should be creating an anonymous user. It's not (during the test — it does when I run the app) which is great, but why not?

Comment: It's hard to say. This depends on how you actually checked that there are no calls. Were there no XHR requests? Any way, in unit tests you never need to use unmocked third-party providers (e.g. Firebase).

Comment: Ah, it is calling Firebase (checked XHR) but oddly no new anonymous user was being created. So how would I mock out AngularFireAuth in the Service?

Comment: I don't use Firebase, but the way you're doing it with mockAngularFireAuth looks pretty much ok to me, that's how it's usually done.

Comment: cheers. This is obviously a question in its own right so I've asked a new one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121529/mock-angularfireauth-when-unit-testing-an-angular-service as I'm not sure how to mock it out. Thanks for help so far, very much appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest to add your attempt with mockAngularFireAuth to the question since it's the right direction. Specifying what problems you currently have with it would also help.

Comment: Btw, I would call 'the easy way' generally the preferable one. Since the problem is primarily TS, it should be solved in TS domain. I personally prefer `Reflect` since it provides the right semantics to the code (accessing private members is what's called reflection), but it isn't really needed here.

Comment: I'm sorry this is where my knowledge is lacking… I am trying to access a private member. I too would prefer to write a few more lines of code rather than shortcut so I can understand it better semantically and digest it easier when I come back to it later. I appreciate this question has taken up a sizeable chunk of your time already, but if you could elaborate or point me in the direction of a resource to educate myself I would be most grateful!

Comment: I guess that some programmers would be confused if they saw `Reflect.get` in code, but yes, the reason why I'm using it is that I don't need to look at object type to know that I'm accessing private member here. `service['authState']` and `(service as any).authState` are both valid ways to do this in TS, but since they are applicable in any case where types went wrong, the semantics behind them is ambiguous.

Comment: I think then Reflect is preferable in this case as it accurately represents what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Sorry @Estus Flask  "The easy way" will not work - in fact, the Method never gets calllled. Jasmine error is  "... to have been called once. It was called 0 times."  You can add `//@ts-ignore` just before the call, as the kind of Methods call (Private, Protected, etc.) it's a TypeScript thing. Does not exist on JavaScript, once transpiled.

Comment: @PedroFerreira There's likely a problem at your side. The error means that a spy really wasn't called. If `service.authState` is a spy that was called, 'the easy way` physically cannot prevent the assertion from working correctly, it works exactly like `expect(service.authState).toBe(null)` JS would. It's not a good idea to use `ts-ignore` where a narrow approach can be used. Imagine something like `//@ts-ignore exepct(service.authState).tobe(null)`.

Comment: That's what I told you, @Estus Flask: Jasmine just doesn't "do" the Spy, when you reference the Method through strings.  Have you ever try it...?  As it also does not do it if the Method to spy on is a getter, for instances...

Comment: @PedroFerreira I'm not sure what you mean. This is not specific to Jasmine. It's how JS works, there's no difference between `service.authState` and `service['authState']`, they are evaluated exactly the same way. And FWIW, TS `(service as any).authState` is transpiled to JS `service.authState`. The question doesn't address getters, so doesn't the answer, there's spyOnProperty in Jasmine for that, and yes, it cannot be accessed as `service.getter`, this needs to be done another way, the most simple way is to store a spy that spyOnProperty returns to a variable.

Comment: @PedroFerreira  Can you post a question that explains your case in details? I have reasons to assume that the you have isn't specific to the thing we discuss, i.e. you have different problem than the OP and it's not enough to do what the answer suggests to solve it. The question was how to access a prop that is labeled as `private` in TS. The answer explains how. Also, you mentioned "the easy way". does this mean that "the hard way" worked for you?

Comment: Yeap @Estus Flask. Entirely! The 3rd 'This answer is useful' vote on your answer is mine! ;-)