# Mock AngularFireAuth When Unit Testing an Angular Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firebase, jasmine, angularfire2

I have an `authService` which when instantiated subscribes to `AngularFireAuth`'s Observable `authState` and sets the services' internal (private) property `authState`.

So I can unit test `authService` I highjack the services' internal `authState` with `Reflect.get/set` in my test specs so I can control its value.

**The problem is of course `authService` is still subscribing to `AngularFireAuth`'s Observable `authState` during its instantiation** and I don't want, nor need it to.

I *presume* I need to mock out AngularFireAuth which fakes a subscription and doesn't actually communicate to Firebase? New to unit tests I am at a loss as to how I should do this.

### auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private authState: firebase.User;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { this.init(); }

  private init(): void {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((authState) => {
      if (authState === null) {
        this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
          .then((authState) => {
            this.authState = authState;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw new Error(error.message);
          });
      } else {
        this.authState = authState;
      }

      console.log(authState);
    }, (error) => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
  }

  public get currentUid(): string {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.uid : undefined;
  }

  public get currentUser(): firebase.User {
    return this.authState ? this.authState : undefined;
  }

  public get currentUserObservable(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
  }

  public get isAnonymous(): boolean {
    return this.authState ? this.authState.isAnonymous : false;
  }

  public get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.authState;
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

### auth.service.spec.ts

```
import { async, fakeAsync, inject, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
// import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

const authState = {
  isAnonymous: true,
  uid: '17WvU2Vj58SnTz8v7EqyYYb0WRc2'
} as firebase.User;

describe('AuthService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseAppConfig)],
      providers: [
        AngularFireAuth,
        AuthService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should be defined', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  }));

  it('.currentUser should be anonymous', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    Reflect.set(service, 'authState', authState);

    expect(service.currentUser).toBe(authState);
  }));

  it('.currentUser should be undefined', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service.currentUser).toBe(undefined);
  }));

  it('.currentUserObservable should be anonymous', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    Reflect.set(service, 'authState', authState);

    service.currentUserObservable.subscribe((value) => {
      expect(value).toBe(authState);
    });
  }));

  it('.currentUserObservable should be undefined', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    service.currentUserObservable.subscribe((value) => {
      expect(value).toBe(undefined);
    });
  }));

  it('.currentUid should be of type String', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    Reflect.set(service, 'authState', authState);

    expect(service.currentUid).toBe(authState.uid);
  }));

  it('.currentUid should be undefined', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service.currentUid).toBe(undefined);
  }));

  it('.isAnonymous should be false', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service.isAnonymous).toBe(false);
  }));

  it('.isAnonymous should be true', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    Reflect.set(service, 'authState', authState);

    expect(service.isAnonymous).toBe(true);
  }));
});
```

For bonus points the two excluded tests (`.currentUserObservable should be anonymous` and `.currentUserObservable should be undefined`) throw the error `Error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out` but only when I log to the console during `authService`'s instantiation. I'm wondering why this would be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I needed to create and spy on `mockAngularFireAuth`'s `authState` and return an Observable which I can subscribe to and expect inside the `onSuccess` or `onError` functions, a la:

```
import { TestBed, async, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { MockUser} from './mock-user';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

describe('AuthService', () => {
  // An anonymous user
  const authState: MockUser = {
    displayName: null,
    isAnonymous: true,
    uid: '17WvU2Vj58SnTz8v7EqyYYb0WRc2'
  };

  const mockAngularFireAuth: any = {
    auth: jasmine.createSpyObj('auth', {
      'signInAnonymously': Promise.reject({
        code: 'auth/operation-not-allowed'
      }),
      // 'signInWithPopup': Promise.reject(),
      // 'signOut': Promise.reject()
    }),
    authState: Observable.of(authState)
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: mockAngularFireAuth },
        { provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthService }
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([ AuthService ], (service: AuthService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  …

  describe('catastrophically fails', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      const spy = spyOn(mockAngularFireAuth, 'authState');

      spy.and.returnValue(Observable.throw(new Error('Catastrophe')));
    });

    describe('AngularFireAuth.authState', () => {
      it('should invoke it’s onError function', () => {
        mockAngularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(null,
          (error: Error) => {
            expect(error).toEqual(new Error('Catastrophe'));
          });
      });
    });
  });
  …
});
```